# Extracting information concerning a the surface of a 3D volume from an imagestack in python

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, scikit-image

I have a tiff image stack that I've used to reconstruct into a 3D volume. The stack contains 'slices' of the object which is a cylinder. I'm attempting to extract information concerning the surface of the cylinder (roughness, local gradients) using scikit image now and am struggling to find the correct function which would allow me to extract said information.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of experiment?

Comment: You probably need to use a marching cubes algorithm to extract a surface from your 3d data, e.g. `verts, faces = skimage.measure.marching_cubes(im3d, 0)` and then perform your analyses on the resulting mesh.

Comment: For the analyses on the mesh you could use surface normals correspond to the gradient and there are several approaches for quantifying local "roughness" of a mesh, e.g. http://liris.cnrs.fr/glavoue/travaux/revue/TAP-2008.pdf